# Codeigniter multiple database, conn_id returns object even if connection fails

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2

I have been reading several posts plus the official guides about how to connect more than one database in CI. I currently connect to the default application database using the standard database.php configuration and load the other database on the fly when needed. The main purpose of this part of the app is to have an "import" feature where the users user inputs the foreign database connection data on the fly when requested.

As long as the second database connection data is correctly set, the app works like a breeze. When there's an error in the connection config I didn't find a working method to evaluate that a connection could not be estabilished to the other database.

I found out that I could check if $db->conn_id is false to eventually return an error to the user but for some reasons it returns an object no matter what.

This is a brief example of what I'm doing inside the model:

```
function plugin_subscribers_import_sfguard($channel_id)
{
    // Get the channel object by its ID
    $channel = $this->get_channel_by('id',$channel_id);

    // Set the preferences for the second database
    // from the channel informations we retrieved
    $db['hostname'] = $channel->host;
    $db['username'] = $channel->user;
    $db['password'] = $channel->password;
    $db['database'] = $channel->db;
    $db['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
    $db['pconnect'] = FALSE;
    $db['db_debug'] = TRUE;

    // Open the connection to the 2nd database
    $other_db = $this->load->database($db,TRUE);

    if ( ! $other_db->conn_id )
    {
        // This never gets executed as $other_db->conn_id always
        // returns: "resource(34) of type (mysql link)"
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        // Execute the rest of the import script
        $other_db->select('*');
        $other_db->from('sf_guard_user');
        $other_db->join('sf_guard_user_profile',
                        'sf_guard_user_profile.id=sf_guard_user.id',
                        'inner');
        $query = $other_db->get();
    }
}
```

I wonder if there's something I didn't get out of the whole thing or if I'm using the wrong logic to evaluate if the secondary database has a proper connection open.

I also tried to try/catch the connection issue with no success.

Thanks in advance for all the support you can offer.
Federico

Answer (score 0):

It's because by setting the second parameter to TRUE (boolean) the function will return the database object and in the `DB.php` there is a function `DB` and the last code block is

```
function &DB($params = '', $active_record_override = NULL)
{
    // ...

    $driver = 'CI_DB_'.$params['dbdriver'].'_driver';
    $DB = new $driver($params);

    if ($DB->autoinit == TRUE)
    {
        $DB->initialize();
    }

    if (isset($params['stricton']) && $params['stricton'] == TRUE)
    {
        $DB->query('SET SESSION sql_mode="STRICT_ALL_TABLES"');
    }

    return $DB;
}
```

So, I think, if you call this

```
$other_db = $this->load->database($db,TRUE);
```

wiuthout the `TRUE`

```
$other_db = $this->load->database($db);
```

Then it could give you a different result.

**Update :** if i you want to use

```
$other_db = $this->load->database($db,TRUE);
```

then you can also check for a method availability using [method_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php) function, like

```
$other_db = $this->load->database($db,TRUE);
if( method_exists( $other_db, 'method_name' ) ) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: There's a reason for the TRUE param: I need the object returned for the queries on the second database as you can see from the code: it is also well documented by the CodeIgniter docs.
I tried anyway and the result is "bool(false)" under all circumstances... which is obviously not what I need.

Comment: I think it's giving an empty object, isn't it ?

Comment: That was an interesting suggestion but I tried with method_exists and it always returns true as the object along with its methods gets created even though it is just non-working.